# Redux saga: Calling an action in loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, redux-saga

I have a grid, which subscribes on some topics. I have an array with topic's name.
So in `gridInitialSaga` i want to subscribe on all topics and make it like this:

```js
function* gridInitialSaga() {
  
  //code here
  
  //subscribe to every topic
  yield all(topics.map(topic => put(subscribeToTopic(topic))))

  //code here
}
```

`topics` - array with topic's name

`subscribeToTopic` - my simple action for backend

When code runs, I'm getting error: `TypeError: Cannot define property @@redux-saga/SAGA_ACTION, object is not extensible` at line with topic subscription.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try using `fork` here instead of `put`

Comment: get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

Comment: Show the contents of `subscribeToTopic`

Comment: I can't show original action, but it is the same
`topic => ({
  type: SUBSCRIBE_TO_TOPIC,
  meta: {
    id: getUID(),
    subscribe: {topic},
  },
})`

I use this action in another places and it works great without problems

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `topics` array i get with selector, it can be modified. 
I solve problem like this `yield all([...topics].map(topic => put(subscribeToTopic(topic))))`